# Dictionary wrong order - JSON

Tags: swift, foundation

I am trying to create a dictionary that I can make into a JSON formatted object and send to the server.

Example:

```
    var users = [
[
"First": "Albert", 
"Last": "Einstein", 
    "Address":[
        "Street": "112 Mercer Street",
        "City": "Princeton"]
],
[
"First": "Marie", 
"Last": "Curie", 
    "Address":[
        "Street": "108 boulevard Kellermann",
        "City": "Paris"]]
]
```

I use this function

```
func nsobjectToJSON(swiftObject: NSObject) -> NSString {
    var jsonCreationError: NSError?
    let jsonData: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(swiftObject, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &jsonCreationError)!
    var strJSON = NSString()

    if jsonCreationError != nil {
        println("Errors: \(jsonCreationError)")
    }
    else {
        // everything is fine and we have our json stored as an NSData object. We can convert into NSString
        strJSON =  NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        println("\(strJSON)")
    }
    return strJSON
}
```

But my result is this:

```
[
  {
    "First" : "Albert",
    "Address" : {
      "Street" : "112 Mercer Street",
      "City" : "Princeton"
    },
    "Last" : "Einstein"
  },
  {
    "First" : "Marie",
    "Address" : {
      "Street" : "108 boulevard Kellermann",
      "City" : "Paris"
    },
    "Last" : "Curie"
  }
]
```

**Problem**: why is the last name last? I think it *should* be above address. Please let me know what I am doing wrong with the NSDictionary for this to come out wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated - thank you.

Comment: are you actually relying on the order of the items? You should not. It is a dictionary, a key-value store, the order is of no real importance.

Comment: Ok, yes understand the key-value aspect as opposed to arry[index], but it looks messy when I print it.  Are you sure I have formatted the Dictionary correct?  I am just surprised that "Last" prints after Address.  Is my Dictionary "syntax" correct to achieve what I want ?

Comment: Yes, dictionaries are not ordered, so there's no reason that the order of the keys in the output would be the same as they were in the declaration.

Comment: Ok, and there is no way to print them in same order as they were in the declaration?

Comment: Only if you write the code to sort the keys and print the associated values...

Comment: BTW, we've all pointed out that dictionaries are unordered, but I don't think we've pointed out that, bottom line, that is a well-accepted convention. The order that the strings appear in the JSON dictionary should never matter. Arrays are ordered, but dictionaries are not. Sure, it's confusing the first time you manually examine a JSON dictionary, but rest assured that everything is OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To post what has already been said in comments: Dictionaries are "unordered collections". They do not have any order at all to their key/value pairs. Period.

If you want an ordered collection, use something other than a dictionary. (an array of single-item dictionaries is one way to do it.) You can also write code that loads a dictionary's keys into a mutable array, sorts the array, then uses the sorted array of keys to fetch key/value pairs in the desired order.

You could also create your own collection type that uses strings as indexes and keeps the items in sorted order. Swift makes that straightforward, although it would be computationally expensive.

Comment: Loading dictionary keys into an array and sort is not the way to solve this trouble. Because in many cases, we need to order without any logic, simply i want to have an array like this: `c,d,a,e`. So, the only way is putting a sequense, array to json to notice that this is the order i wanted. This is so annoying. In some language, they don't have this trouble. For an example, it's PHP.

Comment: @TomSawyer, different languages offer different features in their collection types, and make different design trade-offs. In Swift, Objective-C, and a number of other languages, the dictionary type is unordered. PHP is a loosely typed, interpreted language, and the performance of it's dictionary/list type is likely a couple of orders magnitude slower than Swift.

Comment: I know, that's the difference between languages. Don't talk about performance, talk about the convenience. In this particular case, we need to rewrite the API to return suitable json data for Swift only. I've searched about single-item dictionary with Swift but can't find anything. Can use `OrderedDictionary` type, but it's useless if working with json because we have to order the dictionary first.

Comment: @cmp, no. `NSDictionary` is the Objective-C version of a `Dictionary`, and it is also unordered. That won't help anything.

Comment: @Duncan C .  you are write . Please see the answer posted below.I just left that unfinished.

Comment: Note that assuming that the order of key/value pairs is preserved is a coding error. In JSON, a JSONObject is an unordered collection. The order in which the key/value pairs occur is an accident. The protocol makes no promises about ordering. If PHP treats JSONObjects as an ordered type then that is a faulty mapping in PHP.

Comment: @DuncanC Awesome Sir, I've been tried to solve this issues from about to 9 hours and it's finally solves.,Thank you So much Sir :)

Answer (score -2):

I did like this.

```
 let stagesDict = NSDictionary()
 if let strVal = sleepItemDict["stages"] as? NSDictionary {
 stagesDict = strVal
let sortedKeys = (stagesDict.allKeys as! [String]).sorted(by: <) 
 var sortedValues : [Int] = []
  for key in sortedKeys {
     let value = stagesDict[key]!
      print("\(key): \(value)")
      sortedValues.append(value as! Int)
    }
}
```