# Grouping appointments by day in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of date strings (see below). I would like to use this array for my table view, to display times categorised by days (similar to contacts table in iOS contacts app, which is categorised by letters).

As a first step, I would like to group the array of date strings to achieve an array of categorised appointment times (see below), Please advice how I could achieve this ?. I've looked at many examples but did find a similar one on stack overflow.

This is my input

```
let dateStrings = [
"2016-12-20 16:00:00", 
"2016-12-20 16:15:00", 
"2016-12-21 16:00:00", 
"2016-12-22 16:00:00", 
"2016-12-22 16:15:00", 
"2016-12-22 16:30:00"
]
```

My desired output

```
let categorisedAppointmentTimes = [ 
["Tue, 20 Dec" : ["4:00 pm", "4:15 pm"]],
["Wed, 21 Dec" : ["4:00 pm"]],
["Thu, 22 Dec" : ["4:00 pm", "4:15 pm", "4:30 pm"]]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DateFormatter` to parse `String` to `Date` and from `Date` to `String`.

Please also read this to have more understanding about those operators. http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/

```
    var categorisedAppointmentTimes : [String : [String]] = [:]

    let dateStrings = [
        "2016-12-20 16:00:00",
        "2016-12-20 16:15:00",
        "2016-12-21 16:00:00",
        "2016-12-22 16:00:00", 
        "2016-12-22 16:15:00", 
        "2016-12-22 16:30:00"
    ]


    let inputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    let keyDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    keyDateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM"

    let valueDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    valueDateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"


    for dateString in dateStrings {
        let date = inputDateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

        let dateKey = keyDateFormatter.string(from: date!)

        let dateValue = valueDateFormatter.string(from: date!)

        if categorisedAppointmentTimes.index(forKey: dateKey) != nil {
            categorisedAppointmentTimes[dateKey]!.append(dateValue)
        }else{
            categorisedAppointmentTimes[dateKey] = [dateValue]
        }
    }

    print(categorisedAppointmentTimes)

    //["Tue, 20 Dec": ["4:00 PM", "4:15 PM"],
    // "Thu, 22 Dec": ["4:00 PM", "4:15 PM", "4:30 PM"],
    // "Wed, 21 Dec": ["4:00 PM"]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I notice that the days are not in ascending order, I need them to be in ascending order i.e 20, 21,& 22nd.

Comment: yes, you need to sort it if you want, then you cant use dictionary(or at least not in this structure, you probably need to add a field to store the ) to store the seconds 'timeIntervalSince1970'). Dictionaries are "unordered collections ,  you access dictionary value by key, so order does not matter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088973/dictionary-wrong-order-json

Answer (score 0):

I think this will achieve what you want, but it is very specific to this case and you have to make sure that dateStrings are always in the format you shared. "date time"

```
 var categorisedAppointmentTimes : [String : [String]] = [:]
    let dateStrings = [
        "2016-12-20 16:00:00",
        "2016-12-20 16:15:00",
        "2016-12-21 16:00:00",
        "2016-12-22 16:00:00",
        "2016-12-22 16:15:00",
        "2016-12-22 16:30:00"
    ]
    dateStrings.sorted { (s1, s2) -> Bool in
        s1 > s2
    }
    for date in dateStrings {
        let stringComponets = date.components(separatedBy: " ")
        guard let _ = categorisedAppointmentTimes[stringComponets[0]] else {
            categorisedAppointmentTimes[stringComponets[0]]  = [stringComponets[1]]
            continue
        }
        categorisedAppointmentTimes[stringComponets[0]]?.append(contentsOf: [stringComponets[1]])

    }
```